# What is the lifecycle of useEffect inside a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs

I understand `useEffect` is like an event listener on the component that runs on every re-render (ignoring deps).

Is this still true when it's inside a custom hook or does it get destroyed as soon as the custom hook is finished executing? Example code below:

```
export default props => {
  const [data, setDataWithSideEffects] = customHook('initial value');
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={e => setDataWithSideEffects(e)>Click</button>
      <div>{data.title}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

const customHook = initialValue => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialValue);

  const setDataWithSideEffects = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("http://someUrl.com/api")
    const json = await response.json()
    setData(json); 
  }

  // how long does this live?
  useEffect(() => { // other side effects done every render });

  return [data, setDataWithSideEffects];
}
```

Comment: I think it gets called when the component that it gets called in, re-renders. Like with data fetching, for instance. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook

Comment: What do you mean "how long does it live" ?  It gets executed, and that's it

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html